# Why distribution in PDE is so like the distribution in Probability?

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations

I just learnt distribution in PDE class.
Campared with distribution in probability, they have:
Same name
Similar concept for Delta function
Same converge mode(converge as distribution)
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability distributions are  measures, and a measure is a   distribution in the PDE sense.